# glass material mystery

Tags: glass

As you can see in the picture the black things shows thru the glass but the other glass shape doesnt. The other glass shape is the same distance from the glass so its not just out of range.

The other black things only show through the glass when their materials have "screen space refraction" de-selected

The glass must have "screen space refraction" selected to show objets behind it.

Other objects in same the glass material won't show through this glass.

What could be wrong here? Why are the black things visible but not the other glass shape?

Thanks to anyone who knows anything about this!

[image]

Comment: I presume you are using eevee, yes?

Comment: Ok now i understand, eevee cant do this because it doesnt really raytrace! Thanks!